# Simplifying the code to a dictionary comprehension

Tags: python, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

In a directory ***images***, images are named like - ***1_foo.png***, ***2_foo.png***, ***14_foo.png***, etc.

The images are OCR'd and the text extract is stored in a `dict` by the code below -

```py
data_dict = {}

for i in os.listdir(images):
    if str(i[1]) != '_':
        k = str(i[:2])  # Get first two characters of image name and use as 'key'
    else:
        k = str(i[:1])  # Get first character of image name and use 'key'
    # Intiates a list for each key and allows storing multiple entries
    data_dict.setdefault(k, [])
    data_dict[k].append(pytesseract.image_to_string(i))
```

The code performs as expected.
The images can have varying numbers in their name ranging from 1 to 99.
Can this be reduced to a `dictionary comprehension`?

Comment: What have you tried  so far?

Comment: Trying to accumulate (append to list as an example) in a comprehension can be done with side effects, but in general can not be done directly.

Comment: @KlausD. I was happy with the code I wrote to perform the action and came to SO for knowledge. I agree it would have been better to go to Code Review. Apologies!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Here's one way, but I wouldn't recommend it:

```
{k: d.setdefault(k, []).append(pytesseract.image_to_string(i)) or d[k]
 for d in [{}]
 for k, i in ((i.split('_')[0], i) for i in names)}
```

That might be as clean as I can make it, and it's still bad. Better use a normal loop, especially a clean one like Dennis's.

Slight variation (if I do the abuse once, I might as well do it twice):

```
{k: d.setdefault(k, []).append(pytesseract_image_to_string(i)) or d[k]
 for d in [{}]
 for i in names
 for k in i.split('_')[:1]}
```

Edit: kaya3 now posted a *good* one using a dict comprehension. I'd recommend that over mine as well. Mine are really just the dirty results of me being like *"Someone said it can't be done? Challenge accepted!"*.

Comment: But even this requires a `d = {}` beforehand

Comment: @Dennis No it doesn't, it's inside, see the middle line.

Comment: Oh shoot--that's pretty clever and ugly.

Comment: @Dennis That's one reason I wouldn't recommend this :-)

Comment: @HeapOverflow That's pretty clever! Thanks for the suggestion. Following your recommendation, I think I will just stick to the normal loop.

Answer (score 6):

No. Each iteration in a dict comprehension assigns a value to a key; it cannot update an existing value list. Dict comprehensions aren't always better--the code you wrote seems good enough. Although maybe you could write

```py
data_dict = {}

for i in os.listdir(images):
    k = i.partition("_")[0]
    image_string = pytesseract.image_to_string(i)
    data_dict.setdefault(k, []).append(image_string)
```

Comment: Thank you @Dennis! I think your answer is probably the best approach I will have to follow.

Comment: By the way, `from collections import defaultdict` then `data_dict = default_dict(list)`, and you can do `data_dict[k].append(image_string)` inside the loop. I think it's a bit more readable than `setdefault`.

Answer (score 2):

In this case [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) can be useful; you can group the filenames by the numeric part. But making it work is not easy, because the groups have to be contiguous in the sequence.

That means before we can use `groupby`, we need to sort using a key function which extracts the numeric part. That's the same key function we want to group by, so it makes sense to write the key function separately.

```py
from itertools import groupby

def image_key(image):
    return str(image).partition('_')[0]

images = ['1_foo.png', '2_foo.png', '3_bar.png', '1_baz.png']

result = {
    k: list(v)
    for k, v in groupby(sorted(images, key=image_key), key=image_key)
}

# {'1': ['1_foo.png', '1_baz.png'],
#  '2': ['2_foo.png'],
#  '3': ['3_bar.png']}
```

Replace `list(v)` with `list(map(pytesseract.image_to_string, v))` for your use-case.